# How to check an integer field in XML has string value in jaxb unmarshaling

Tags: java, string, jaxb, integer, unmarshalling

I have to check whether I have getting string in integer field in xml when unmarshaling using JAXB.

Implementation Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;

public class JAXBDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      try {         
         String xmlString = "file:///c:/xml/stud.xml";

         // unmarshal XML string to class
         Student st = JAXB.unmarshal(xmlString, Student.class);

         // prints
         System.out.println("Age : "+st.getAge());
         System.out.println("Name : "+st.getName());

      }catch(Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Mapping Class :

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Student{

   String name;
   int age;
   int id;

   public String getName(){
      return name;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public void setName(String name){
      this.name = name;
   }

   public int getAge(){
      return age;
   }

   @XmlElement
   public void setAge(int age){
      this.age = age;
   }

   public int getId(){
      return id;
   }

   @XmlAttribute
   public void setId(int id){
      this.id = id;
   }
}
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<student id="10">
   <age>hello</age>
   <name>Malik</name>
</student>
```

Output:

```
Age : 0
Name : Malik
```

when I give String value in integer field it gives as zero. I have to check how to check an integer field in xml having non numeric value and throw an error.

Comment: I don't know why you promoting this answer for the question. What if the user sends '0'???? Its related to JAXB parsing and not blind regex check

Answer (score 1):

`JAXB` is a convenience class that encompass `JAXBContext`, `Unmarshaller` and other JAXB API libraries to make it easier to perform simple operations.
The problem with it, that it's not really dealing with issues like validating the schemas and performance issues. it'll try to do a "best effort" and ignore issues for not matching data fields, such as `String` in an `int` field.

in order to circumvent that, you'll have to use the JAXB API directly, and validate the schema during the unmarshaling process.

I haven't tested this code, but it should be something similar to this:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Student.class);
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Student st = u.unmarshal(new File(xmlString));
```

you might need to explicitly cast the unmarshal to Student, i.e:

```
Student st = (Student)u.unmarshal(new File(xmlString));
```

Comment: no its not a solution at all or anything do with above scenario.